# How to get the formula cell value(data) using apache poi 3.1

Tags: java, excel, apache, excel-formula, apache-poi

I am using Apache poi-3.1-FINAL-20080629 in my application. here, I have one problem using formula...

My Cell has formula(sheet2!C10) and the data inside this cell is String type (e.g $3,456)...How to access that cell also want to display the formula.

My code Looks like:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
HSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator = new HSSFFormulaEvaluator(sheet, wb);

Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
        System.out.println("\n");
        Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
        while (cells.hasNext()) {

            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();

            int cellType = cell.getCellType();

            if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC == cellType)
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "     ");
            else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING == cellType)
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "     ");
            else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN == cellType)
                System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "     ");
            else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK == cellType)
                System.out.print("BLANK     ");
            else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA == cellType) {
                System.out.print(evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).toString()  );              }   else 
                System.out.print("Unknown cell type " + cellType);

        }

    }
```

evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).toString() is throwing null pointer exception. Please Help!!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK, so first up, Apache POI 3.1 is rather old. The clue is in the jar name - `poi-3.1-FINAL-20080629` dates from 2008, so 6 years ago! It's well worth upgrading, the [number of bug fixes since then is pretty vast....](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.1-final)

As for your problem, I'm fairly sure that you don't want to be calling `evaluator.evaluateInCell`. That's almost never the right method to call

You have three options available to you, depending on what you want to do with your formula cell:

**I want the formula string**

Call [Cell.getCellFormula](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellFormula%28%29) and you'll get back the formula string

**I want the last formula value Excel calculated**

When Excel writes out a file, it normally stores the last evaluated value for the formula, in a cache, to make opening nice and quick. You can read this, if present, from Apache POI. It's only a cache, so it might not always be correct, but it normally is.

You need to call [Cell.getCachedFormulaResultType](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCachedFormulaResultType%28%29), then switch on that, and read the values out using the normal getters, eg

```
int cellType = cell.getCellType();
handleCell(cell, cellType);

private void handleCell(Cell cell, int cellType) {
        if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC == cellType)
            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "     ");
        else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING == cellType)
            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "     ");
        else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN == cellType)
            System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "     ");
        else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK == cellType)
            System.out.print("BLANK     ");
        else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA == cellType)
            handleCell(cell, cell.getCachedFormulaResultType());
        else 
            System.out.print("Unknown cell type " + cellType);
   }
```

**I want Apache POI to calculate the formula result for me**

Your best bet here is to get a [FormulaEvaluator object](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html) and call evaluate:

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

// suppose your formula is in B3
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("B3"); 
Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol()); 

CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);

switch (cellValue.getCellType()) {
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
    System.out.println(cellValue.getBooleanValue());
    break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
    System.out.println(cellValue.getNumberValue());
    break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
    System.out.println(cellValue.getStringValue());
    break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
    break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
    break;

// CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never happen
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
    break;
}
```

The [Apache POI Formula Evaluation page](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) has more on all of these

Comment: Thank you so much Gagravarr. This really helped and worked too. Appreciate the way you explained. Thanks again!!