# Apache-POI in Java is not returning computed cell value

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi

Currently, a java-com bridge is used to load Excel Application in java followed by loading the Excel workbook.  Though computed cell values are accurately retrieved, soon after loading Excel application, CPU usage is reaching 100% and the program is crashing after processing 5 to 7 records.  Unfortunately, the underlying dll, jcom.dll is no longer being maintained or supported.

So, I am trying to get computed cell values from a proprietary spreadsheet using Apache-POI in Java.  Formulas and computations on Sheet 0 are stored as pointers to formulas that are in other hidden sheets in the workbook.  While obtaining the computed value, code is returning pointer to hidden sheet and cell containing formula on that hidden sheet as a String.

Any suggestion to retrieve the computed value or an alternative to POI if it cannot be done in POI?

After running the code shown below, an age value of 39 is expected but the output is shown as

'Unformatted Values'!AD13

[I do not have privileges to paste calculator image and only a link to image is allowed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cl9w.png)

```
public class POICalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 //   To fill cell values in calculator spreadsheet and 
 //   obtain computed cell value
        InputStream ExcelFileToRead;
        try {
          ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\XLS\\NPCalculatorBlack.xls");
          HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
          HSSFWorkbook test = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
          HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
          HSSFRow row; 
          HSSFCell cell;
          String examDate = "04/02/2019";
          String birthDate = "01/01/1980";

// input cell value for F3
          sheet.getRow(2).getCell(5).setCellValue(examDate);
// input cell value for H3
          sheet.getRow(2).getCell(7).setCellValue(birthDate);
          HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);                 
          HSSFFormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();                  
// output computed AGE value from cell B5 - Expected result: 39
          String age = sheet.getRow(4).getCell(1).toString();
          System.out.println(age);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty good question, but might be a duplicate.  Check if the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23018244/684617) will address your situation (third heading: **I want Apache POI to calculate the formula result for me**).  Most of that code you already have in place, so my gut is that you're pretty close to getting what you need.

Comment: @GoldDragonTSU, I saw that post before posting mine.  It did not work.